# Why does it apply the second argument?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand the Interchange law of applicative functor:

```
u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
```

What make me confuse is, the function application `$ y`, consider following example:

```
($ 2) :: (a -> b) -> b
```

Why does the second argument get applied not the first?

Comment: Note that the section `($ 2)` is distinct from the partial application `(($) 2)` -- the latter does apply the "first" argument to `($)`, the former is equivalent to `\f -> f $ 2` i.e. it applies the "second" argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an *operator section*. A few simple examples:

```
Prelude> (/2) <$> [1..8]
[0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0]
Prelude> (:"!") <$> ['a'..'e']
["a!","b!","c!","d!","e!"]
```

The section `(:"!")` is syntactic sugar for `\c -> c:"!"`, i.e. it takes a character `c` and prepends it to the string `"!"`.

Likewise, the section `($ 2)` takes a function `f` and simply *applies* it to the number `2`.

Note that this is different from ordinary *partial application*:

```
Prelude> ((/) 2) <$> [1..8]
[2.0,1.0,0.6666666666666666,0.5,0.4,0.3333333333333333,0.2857142857142857,0.25]
```

Here, I've simply applied the function `(/)` to one fixed argument 2, the *dividend*. This can also be written as a *left section* `(2/)`. But the right section `(/2)` applies `2` as the *divisor* instead.

Comment: The signature of `($)` is `($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`, why it is possible to pass a number to `($)` instead of function?

Comment: It _isn't_ possible, that's not what you're doing there.

Comment: @zero_coding `$` is an infix operator, where the first parameter is written before it, and the second parameter is written after it. `($ 2)` isn't the same as `(2 $)`

Comment: I tried following expression `Prelude> ((+3) $ 3)` and now it is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with operator sections. For example:

```
(5+ )   -- Same as \ x -> 5+x
( +5)   -- Same as \ x -> x+5
```

It's only *operators* you can do this with; normal named functions can only be curried from left to right.

Comment: Normal named functions can be made operators with backticks. Compare `(++"foo")` and ```(`mappend`"foo")```.

Comment: @DanielWagner Sure. But then you've made it an operator. ;-) My point is there isn't a way to, say, miss out argument #6 or something...

Answer (score 0):

Haskell  cheat sheet *operator sections* entry could be:

```
(a `op` b)  =  (a `op`) b  =  (`op` b) a  =  (op) a b
```

When `op` is an actual operator (not an alpha-numerical name), backticks aren't needed.

The above can be seen as partially applying implicitly defined lambda expressions:

```
(a `op`) b  =  (a `op` b)  =  (\y -> a `op` y) b  = (\x y -> x `op` y) a b  =  op a b
(`op` b) a  =  (a `op` b)  =  (\x -> x `op` b) a  = (\y x -> x `op` y) b a  =  flip op b a
```

If a function `f` expects more than two arguments eventually, we can similarly create its curried version by partially applying an explicit lambda expression:

```
(\y z x -> f x y z) b c    -- = (\x -> f x b c) 
(\x z y -> f x y z) a c    -- = (\y -> f a y c) 
(\x y z -> f x y z) a b    -- = (\z -> f a b z)
```

The last case is equivalent to just `f a b`, and the second to `(flip . f) a c`:

```
g b c a = f a b c = flip f b a c = flip (flip f b) c a = (flip . flip f) b c a
g a c b = f a b c = flip (f a) c b = (flip . f) a c b
g a b c = f a b c
```